# Update null values of all Columns Dynamically in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, multiple-columns, updates

I have a data set of 75 columns and 411274 rows of which many of the entries are `null` or `NA` I want to replace all those values with `Data_not_available` is there a way to do it dynamically rather than entering each column name to check and update the data? I don't want to use the code similar to this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE 1 = CASE 
      WHEN column1 is null OR column2 is null OR ..... OR columnN is null THEN 1
      ELSE 0
      END
```

this is consuming a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regexp_replace UDF to perform what you want.

```
regexp_replace(string INITIAL_STRING, string PATTERN, string REPLACEMENT)
```

> Returns the string resulting from replacing all substrings in
>   INITIAL_STRING that match the java regular expression syntax defined
>   in PATTERN with instances of REPLACEMENT. For example,
>   regexp_replace("foobar", "oo|ar", "") returns 'fb.' Note that some
>   care is necessary in using predefined character classes: using '\s' as
>   the second argument will match the letter s; '\s' is necessary to
>   match whitespace, etc.

So in your case you could use something like:

```
SELECT
   regexp_replace(column1, 'null|NA', 'Data_not_available') as column1,
   column2,
   column3,
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

COALESCE and IF function will help you to do it dynamically. As you can see the computed projection ( select ) works as do you want.

```
create table test_3(field String);
insert into test_3 values( null ), ( "NA"), ("A good value");

select * from test_3;
+---------------+--+
| test_3.field  |
+---------------+--+
| NULL          |
| NA            |
| A good value  |
+---------------+--+

select if ( coalesce( field, "NA") = "NA", "Data Not Available", field ) from test_3;
+---------------------+--+
|         _c0         |
+---------------------+--+
| Data Not Available  |
| Data Not Available  |
| A good value        |
+---------------------+--+
```